# Pass a string in function parameter

Tags: html, angularjs

I try to call a function with a string as parameter

```
<input type="checkbox" value={{user.name}} id={{user.name}} ng-click="toggleSelection({{user.name}})">
```

but I have this error

```
Syntax Error: Token 'Marcus' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 20 of the expression [toggleSelection(Julian Marcus)] starting at [Julian Marcus)].
```

i've tried `toggleSelection('{{user.name}}')` and `toggleSelection("{{user.name}}")` but still the same problem

Comment: wrap it in single quotes `toggleSelection('{{user.name}}')`

Comment: Also you need quotes around value and id attributes as the string contain a space.

Comment: I think there is no need of double or single quote or any interpolation. you can just pass variable.

Comment: I would also recommend to use ng-model="user.name" instead of value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @TOM has answered the question but doen't explained why it doen't work.

You should not use `{{}}` inside `ng-click` because [**`ng-click`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) does direct access do the scope variable without using interpolation `{{}}` directive.

The error you are finding because while evaluating `toggleSelection({{user.name}})` this function `$parser` throws `Syntax Error:`

You could just fixed it by using direct scope variable.

```
ng-click="toggleSelection(user.name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need angular to parse your string, just pass the object `user.name`

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       value="{{user.name}}" 
       id="{{user.name}}"
       ng-click="toggleSelection(user.name)">
```

I've also added quotes around your `value` and `id` properties.